# How to redeclare a block-scoped variable in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

My project dependents on some module which dependents on `@types/node`, and I hope to don't use `process` variable in my project, so I create a file `globals.d.ts` in my project with the following content:

```
export {}
declare global {
  const process: never
}
```

And I got an error: `TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'process'.`

Is there any way to redeclare a variable in TypeScript?

Comment: The specific problem is that the block is the global scope. `let` and `const` are block scoped. You could shadow them in a more narrow scope but that isn't what you want to do. You could look into the tslint `ban` rule and give it error severity.

Comment: @AluanHaddad It's a TypeScript error rather than lint error

Comment: I know. I was suggesting using tslint's ban rule as an alternative to the redeclaration as never